# Is it possible to download map in runtime?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm developing an Android application and I need to implement offline maps. For this I use OpenStreetMap, or rather osmdroid.
I need to implement the loading of maps when executing the program based on where the user is located. My question is, is it possible to load maps when I run the application and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Off device, using MOBAC, you can follow this guide: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles#mobile-atlas-creator-mobac

On device, using osmdroid, you can use the cache manager:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles#use-osmdroids-cache-manager-on-device---version-52

There are several links to examples and source code, such as the one in the osmdroid sample app, which is on the play store or available for download on github.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/cache/SampleCacheDownloader.java